# AVplayer Audio routing to speakers and headphones

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i am trying to route the audio to headphone when headphone is plugged in and and play it via iPhone speakers when there is no headphones connected.

i have tried the the following

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, audioRouteChangeListenerCallback, nil); 

void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
                                       void                      *inUserData,
                                       AudioSessionPropertyID    inPropertyID,
                                       UInt32                    inPropertyValueSize,
                                       const void                *inPropertyValue
                                       ) {
    DetailViewController *controller = (__bridge_transfer DetailViewController *) inUserData;
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

    CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = (CFDictionaryRef)inPropertyValue;

    CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef = (CFNumberRef)CFDictionaryGetValue (routeChangeDictionary, CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason) );
    SInt32 routeChangeReason;
    CFNumberGetValue (routeChangeReasonRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &routeChangeReason);

    if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {
        NSLog(@"UnPlugged");
[controller headphoneIsPlugged]; 
        UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
    } else if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_NewDeviceAvailable) {
        NSLog(@"Plugged in");
    }
}
```

the function headphone is not being called at all. the program is not even going to that part of the section.

now when i plug out the headphone the audio just stops and nothing its not being played via the speaker.

inside the audiolister i tried to put the following
[controller.avplayer play];
but still nothing is happening.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the instance of `DetailViewController` when you are adding the listener. This will be passed in as user data. Without this `(__bridge_transfer DetailViewController *) inUserData;` would return nil.

Your code would be something like this if you call it from within your `DetailViewController`:

```
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (
   kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange,
   audioRouteChangeListenerCallback,
   (__bridge void *)(self)
);
```